# Non-English characters don't appear on Visual Studio Code terminal screen

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, vscode-debugger

I'm using the latest version of Visual Studio Code. I'm trying to debug a python script. I see on the terminal screen a command like this:

```
PS C:\Users\Özkan TÜZEMEN\Desktop\test>  & 'c:\program files\Python\Python310\python.exe' 'c:\Users\zkan TZEMEN\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2022.2.1924087327\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy\launcher' '57927' '--' 'c:\Python files\Untitled-1.py'
```

I see that Visual Studio Code ignores non English characters and it causes  [Errno 2] No such file or directory error.

How can I fix that?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think its possible since Turkhis letters are not supported. However maybe u can try to install a new font, or make your program completely.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I realized it is not about the application I'm writing, it is about Powershell's compatibility with umlaut characters. Using cmd as terminal I have no issue but with Powershell I do.